# ClassCastException[java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double] in Elasticsearch when trying to sort by an additional field

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch

I'm having an issue where Elasticsearch running on Amazon Elasticsearch Service (v1.5 and v2.3) keeps returning the following error:

```
{u'status': 503, u'error': u'ReduceSearchPhaseException[Failed to execute phase [query], [reduce] ]; nested: ClassCastException[java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double]; '}
```

Here's the elasticsearch query in python:

```
def search_es(q, indices):
    es = get_search_client()
    search_body = {
        "sort": [ {'importance_score': 'desc'}, '_score', ],
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "display_name": q
            }
        }
    }
    try:
        res = es.search(index=indices, body=search_body)
    except TransportError as e:
        assert False, e.info

    data = []
    for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
        data.append(hit['_source'])
    return data
```

The code above runs perfectly when I have an elasticsearch docker container running locally. But it somehow fails in our test environment using AWS version of ES.

If I remove the bolded portion here, the query runs without errors (although with undesirable ordering):

"sort": [ **{'importance_score': 'desc'},** '_score', ],

Which leads me to believe there's something up with that score. importance_score is just a normal key that's calculated prior to indexing, and it has a maximum value of 19. I've tried variations of it by casting it as float, int, and long before indexing. All of them work locally but return the same error on test env.

Upgrading to ES v2.3 changes the structure of the error message but returns essentially the same error.

What might be causing this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: What's the mapping of the `importance_score` field? Do you have other types that have the same field in it? And what's the error in ES 2.3?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding to this, but the issue was that importance_score got automapped to different types based on document. Forcing it all to be long by using explicit mapping solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, importance_score for different document types was getting dynamically mapped to different primitive types. Forcing all mappings to use long for importance_score fixed the issue.